# Alimentar Textarea com campo do banco

Tags: php, html, ajax, oracle

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte: Preciso alimentar uma `textarea`, a cada minuto, com o resultado da query abaixo:

```
$consulta = OCIParse($ora_conexao,"Select
                                   pcn.romaneio       Romaneio
                                   from
                                   PCN_ROMANEIO_RESUMO    pcn
                                   Where
                                   pcn.status = "A"
                                   order by 1");

OCIDefineByName($consulta,"ROMANEIO",$romaneio);

OCIExecute($consulta);

while (OCIFetch($consulta)){

"exibir na textarea"

}
```

Tentei colocando no `meta-tag` um refresh a cada minuto, mas o resultado não aparece na `textarea`. Na última tentativa, colocando dentro do while a tag `<textarea>` ele criou uma para cada resultado....

PS: Essa página será exibida em um coletor, que tem IE 6 apenas....

Existe uma forma de fazer isso?

O que tentei:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/PesquisaRomaneio.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/styles.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>::: SIG - Sistemas de Informações Gerenciais - Peccin S.A.:::</title>

<body>
<form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="POST" action="login.php" autocomplete="off">
  <fieldset>
    <legend><b><center><img src="images/logo.png" width="55" height="22"/><br>Coleta de dados - WMS:</center></b></legend>
    <br>ROMANEIOS PARA CONFERÊNCIA:<br>
    <input type="text" id="busca" onClick="buscarRomaneio()" autofocus />
    <div id="resultado"></div>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="conteudo"></div>

     <input type="button" onclick = "location.href='/coleta/Separacao';" value="SEPARAÇÃO" style="height:35px; width:80px;">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
     <input type="button" onclick = "location.href='/coleta/Conferencia';" value="CONFERÊNCIA" style="height:35px; width:80px;">
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PesquisaRomaneio.js**

```
var req;

// FUNÃ‡ÃƒO PARA BUSCA MOTORISTA
function buscarRomaneio() {

// Verificando Browser
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
   req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// Arquivo PHP juntamente com o valor digitado no campo (mÃ©todo GET)
//var url = "PesquisaUsuario_Busca.php?cracha="+cracha;

// Chamada do mÃ©todo open para processar a requisiÃ§Ã£o
//req.open("Get", url, true);

// Quando o objeto recebe o retorno, chamamos a seguinte funÃ§Ã£o;
req.onreadystatechange = function() {

    // Exibe a mensagem "Buscando MOtorista..." enquanto carrega
    if(req.readyState == 1) {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = 'Buscando Usuário...';
    }

    // Verifica se o Ajax realizou todas as operaÃ§Ãµes corretamente
    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {

    // Resposta retornada pelo busca.php
    var resposta = req.responseText;

    // Abaixo colocamos a(s) resposta(s) na div resultado
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resposta;
    }
}
//req.send(null);
}
```

**PesquisaRomaneio.php**

```
<?php
// Dados do banco
include 'config.php';

//Inicia a consulta ao banco Oracle, com os dados informados pelo cliente.
$consulta2 = OCIParse($ora_conexao,"select * from PCN_ROMANEIO_COLETA");

//aqui prepara a consulta, nome da coluna e a variavel retorno da consulta
OCIDefineByName($consulta2,"ROMANEIO",$v_romaneio);

// executa a consulta
OCIExecute($consulta2);

/* Gera um arry com o resultado para mandar para o Ajax.
*/
while (OCIFetch($consulta2)){
    echo "<td>" . $v_romaneio . "</td><br />";
}


OCIFreeStatement($consulta2);

// Acentuação
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true);
?>
```

Comment: posta o seu JavaScript e HTML ai para que possamos entender melhor o que você está fazendo.

Comment: Aparentemente esta tudo certo, o problema seria somente fazer a requisicao a cada 1 minuto?

Comment: O código está um pouco bagunçado, admito, mas basicamente seria isso, fazer a requisição a cada minuto. Ele deu um erro de XML na execução, mas corrigi e abriu o valor na página, agora só falta o minuto em minuto...Obrigado

Comment: Diego deletou a outra pergunta sobre ajax porque? Eu estava respondendo :/

Comment: Foi mal, vou reabrir ela. Não resolvi o problema, mas como sairam negativando fechei. Já ta aberta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ja que falta so fazer a requisicao a cada minuto eu iria de [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), ou [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

#### setTimeout()

```
if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {

    // Resposta retornada pelo busca.php
    var resposta = req.responseText;

    // Abaixo colocamos a(s) resposta(s) na div resultado
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resposta;
    //primeiro argumento é a funcao a ser executada, o segunta o tempo que vai levar ate a funcao ser disparada, em milisegundos.
    setTimeout(buscarRomaneio, 60000);
}
```

Coloquei o `setTimeout()` no fim da requisicao, ou seja assim que acabar a requisicao vai esperar 1 minuto e fazer uma nova requisicao e assim por diante.

O unico probleminha seria se a requisicao retornar um erro tipo status 404, ai quebraria o ciclo.

#### setInterval()

```
function buscarRomaneio() {
    //seu codigo da requisicao.....
}
setInterval(buscarRomaneio, 60000);
```

A vantagem aqui é nao ter que se preocupar se a requisicao retornou erro ou nao, por que a funcao vai ser chamada infinitamente, independente do status da requisicao.

Comment: Cara, sem palavras. Muito obrigado. Da forma que eu ia fazer ia moer a memória, que já é pouca, do coletor. Assim eu jogo pra rede e deixa ela que se vire. Obrigado!